# VSTO Excel Customization not loading in workbooks : Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I am working with VSTO Excel project and customizing the xltx template. First release of the project is working correctly and users created workbooks from that template. I have added new worksheet and some controls in the template and released new version of project. This is working correctly only if user creates new workbook from template but all previously created workbook are throwing exception

> "Element not found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)". Any
>   suggestion?
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IHostItemProvider.GetHostExtender(String
>   extenderType, String extenderCookie, IntPtr& extenderObject)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.Office.Tools.IHostItemProvider.GetHostExtender(Type
>   primaryType, String primaryCookie)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlSiteImpl..ctor(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IHostItemProvider hostItemProvider, String
>   primaryCookie, String identifier, Object containerComponent, UInt32
>   officeVersion, Control control, _OLEObject extenderControl, Boolean
>   isDynamic)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.FactoryImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Factory.CreateControlSite(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IHostItemProvider hostItemProvider, String
>   primaryCookie, String identifier, Object containerComponent, Control
>   control)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button..ctor(Factory factory,
>   IHostItemProvider hostItemProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
>   String cookie, String extenderCookie, Object container, String
>   identifier)    at CampaignMapping.Excel.Beta.Tag.InitializeControls() 
>   at CampaignMapping.Excel.Beta.Tag.Initialize()
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases
>   executionPhases)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.LoadEntryPoints(IntPtr
>   serviceProvider)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************

(remainder removed for clarity of question as unnecessary for trouble-shooting of the reason)

Comment: When you re-built your document-level customization did you change the VERSION? The old workbooks need to have the earlier version - they can't change to the new one - they're structured differently. You need to update the version number when you change the solution before you deploy. That will put the updated version in a different folder, while the older version can find its code in the original folder. See Deploying an Office Solution and look at the diagram under "Roll back a solution..." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx#Update